# Is it possible for a list of tuples containing multiple strings to be sorted alphabetically by an unknown index? Python

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, tuples

Novice python learner here. I'll go straight to the point. I have a list of tuples, each containing names in some order. I want to sort these tuples alphabetically.

```
sample_lst = [

('Bessie', 'Buttercup', 'Bella', 'Blue', 'Belinda', 'Beatrice', 'Sue', 'Betsy'), 
('Bessie', 'Buttercup', 'Bella', 'Blue', 'Belinda', 'Betsy', 'Beatrice', 'Sue')
('Bessie', 'Belinda', 'Betsy', 'Blue', 'Bella', 'Buttercup', 'Sue', 'Beatrice')
('Bessie', 'Belinda', 'Beatrice', 'Sue', 'Betsy', 'Buttercup', 'Bella', 'Blue')
]
```

For example, the fourth tuple would alphabetically come before the third tuple because of the difference between Betsy and Beatrice.

As you can see, there is a small list of tuples each containing names (this is a sample of a much larger set of tuples), and I need to sort them alphabetically.

The part that makes this problem difficult for me is that there is no set value to sort it by. If I could just sort all the tuples by the first index, I would've done that, but in this case, the logic doesn't apply. Sometimes the difference between two tuples is at index 4, and at other times it it could be 2.

```
cows = ['Bessie', 'Buttercup', 'Belinda', 'Beatrice', 'Bella', 'Blue', 'Betsy','Sue']
cow_permutations = itertools.permutations(cows, 8)
```

Hopefully this snippet gives you a much clearer idea of what I am trying to do. As you can, I am taking a list of cow names, and using itertools to find every possible permutation. I just need to sort them alphabetically.

At first I overthought the problem and tried to use lambda functions to somehow sort them in a particular range, to no avail.

Then, I resorted to much simpler methods such as .sort()

```
cow_permutations.sort()
```

this also failed, I thought I could sort the gigantic list of tuples in that way. All I got was a 'itertools.permutations' object has no attribute 'sort' error.

I think I've tried everything within my abilities as a beginner. If someone could point me toward a way in which I can sort the list of tuples alphabetically, or perhaps offer a different way I can go about finding the permutations of all the cow name orders so I can make the code less messy - I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking multiple questions here, first being how to convert cow_permutations from a permutations object to list of tuples. You can do this by casting to a list.

```
cow_permutations_list = list(itertools.permutations(cows, 8))
```

The simplest way of sorting your list will be sorting by a single, combined string.

```
cow_permutations_list.sort(key=lambda x:"".join([k.lower() for k in x]))
```

If you need to sort by a specific range of indices, you can supply it to the input of the lambda function.

```
cow_permutations_list.sort(key=lambda x:"".join([k.lower() for k in x[start_index:end_index]]))
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `"".join()` in the `key`? By default, tuples are already sorted in lexicographical order. Concatenating the strings in the key actually might fail to produce lexicographic order; for instance: `l = [('aa', 'bb'),('aaa', 'aa')]; print(sorted(l, key=lambda t: ''.join(t))); print(sorted(l))`.

Comment: @Stef true but the question is about alphabetical sorting.

Comment: Which is, at best, ambiguous. It also assumes the OP is familiar with the distinction between "lexicographical" and "alphabetical" and used the most appropriate one. In this particular case, the difference is somewhat subtle, and certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: @Stef it's possible. Feel free to add your own solution as an answer.